# Finding date before given number of months from a given date

Tags: java, date

I have a date say for e.g. current date which is 19/04/2013

And I have number of months given say for e.g. 10

I want to find out the date falling before 10 months from 19/04/2013.

How to achieve it in Java?

For example, if I want to find out date before a week, I can achieve as below:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(myDate);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
```

But how to find the same for months ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could do something similar to your example:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(myDate);
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -10);
Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
```

It'll set `newDate` to a date 10 months before `myDate`.

Answer (score 2):

Using jodatime this is so much easier and verbose:

```
 LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("19/04/2013", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
 LocalDate result = date.minus(Months.TEN);
 System.out.println(result.toString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```